# Has anyone seen a simplex library for javascript/nodejs

Tags: node.js, v8, mathematical-optimization, simplex

I've been writing a lot of my scripts in NodeJs, but I need to use something like the [GLPK](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/glpk.htm) libraries in order to handle some of the optimizations in my scripts.  Has anyone heard of a javascript driver?  I wonder how hard it would be to port coin to a V8 library.. probably above my pay grade.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if its what the OP is looking for, but I'm working on something [here](https://github.com/JWally/jsLPSolver) that might work. You would use it like this:

```
var solver = new Solver,
    results,
    model = {
    optimize: "profit",
    opType: "max",
    constraints: {
        "Costa Rican" : {max: 200},
        "Etheopian": {max: 330}
    },
    variables: {
        "Yusip": {"Costa Rican" : 0.5, "Etheopian": 0.5, profit: 3.5},
        "Exotic": {"Costa Rican" : 0.25, "Etheopian": 0.75, profit: 4}
    }
};

results = solver.solve(model);
console.log(results);
```

Where the results would end up being:

```
{feasible: true, Yusip: 270, Exotic: 260, result: 1985}
```

Its probably not the fastest solver in the world, but its easy enough to work with.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript Simplex Libraries

- [SimplexJS](https://github.com/IainNZ/SimplexJS)
- [SimpleSimplex](https://github.com/lowensk/SimpleSimplex)
- [YASMIJ.js](https://github.com/LarryBattle/YASMIJ.js/)

YASMIJ Example:

```
var input = {
    type: "maximize",
    objective : "x1 + 2x2 - x3",
    constraints : [
        "2x1 + x2 + x3 <= 14",
        "4x1 + 2x2 + 3x3 <= 28",
        "2x1 + 5x2 + 5x3 <= 30"
    ]
};
YASMIJ.solve( input ).toString();
// returns
"{"result":{"slack1":0,"slack2":0,"slack3":0,"x1":5,"x2":4,"x3":0,"z":13}}"
```

Comment: I have tried all of these and they are junk unfortunately :(
_SimplexJS_ is for mixed-linear program (doesn't actually implement the Simplex method, seems to have just chosen that name for fun).
_SimpleSimplex_ has `document.write` in the code... not something you are going to use inside another project, just a demo.
_YASMIJ.js_ never made it out of beta and you pass the objective function in as a string, which can't be a good sign...

Comment: There are two completely different optimisations algorithms that both go by the name "simplex algorithm":  The linear programming optimisation problem where the space is bounded by a simplex and the solution point is moved from vertex to vertex, and the Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm for optimising an arbitrary function in a continuous space by repeatedly making a simplex and estimating the integral within that simplex.  Super-confusing!  Stumps many people searching for implementations.  The example above is a linear programming problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Comment: Be careful - YASMIJ.js works only for maximization (type: "maximize"). Moreover, currently is not supported - it is written in the readme.

Comment: SimpleSimplex is a nelder mead optimizer, not a linear programming solver.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help, but please have a look at [numericjs.com](http://www.numericjs.com/). It's a javascript numerical analysis library that I'm working on that has a rudimentary implementation of a linear programming algorithm.

Comment: numericsjs is seriously busted and hasn't been updated since 2012. Don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

[GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) has actually been ported to JavaScript using [emScripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten). The resulting js is about 1 MB minified and 230 KB zipped.

As of today August 2018

1) Last committed Dec 2015: 
https://github.com/hgourvest/node-glpk

2) Last committed Dec 2017:
https://github.com/jvail/glpk.js

Try them out!